# one-to-one relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to achieve a simple 1 to 1 relation in Rails 3 where a user can connect a bank account.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bank
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bank
  attr_accessible :bank_attributes
end

class Bank < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Route

```
resources :users do
  resources :bank
```

Now when i build a new bank object for a user in users/1/bank/new like this:

```
def new
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  @bank = @user.build_bank
end
```

I get an error on my for which looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@bank) do |f| %>
```

The error is:

```
undefined method `banks_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa7bd090f08>:0x007fa7c0545b40>
```

My goal is to have a separate form for a user to add there bank account information.. Hope someone can help me in the right direction to do this. I also use ActiveAdmin and the relation with forms etc works fine there.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: though not sure, i guess you need to declare the route resource as plural even though it is 1-1 association. so try `resources :banks`. if you do so, you will need to rename controller to `BanksController` in `banks_controller.rb`

Comment: Thx HungryCoder your solution worked out.. I still dont get why bank had to be plural but it works now.

Comment: i'm adding it as answer so that you can accept it. it will help both of us :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare resource in plural form regardless of the association type.

So, your resource declaration

```
resources :users do
  resource :banks
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since bank is nested under user, you need to give the user to the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@user, @bank]) do |f| %>
```

In addition, your routes file should be

```
resources :users do
  resource :bank
```

This will give you a user_bank_path for a user

Comment: i should have post this in my question right away but i've tried to add the user to the form and it gives the error: undefined method `user_banks_path' so it keeps been pural :( i don't understand why..

Comment: HungryCoder was right.. i've edit bank to banks in routes and naming and it works now.. weird no?